# How to find my AWS SES is not in sandbox mode in AWS console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Getting error Email address not verified. However upon going through many articles, came to know that SES account need to be moved to production. The question arises when my colleage said that mail configured in AWS SES in our company seems moved to production and it is not in sandbox.

So to prove it right or wrong how to check our AWS SES account been moved production? Do i need to look for specific propery which am ignoring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click "Sending Statistics" in the console.

If you don't see a message saying that "Your Amazon SES account has 'sandbox' access in region xxxxx" then you are not sandboxed in the selected region.

Be sure you are looking at the correct region -- the same region your client is using -- each region is independent, so you can have production access in some regions, but not others.